# Помогите подправить код JavaScript Replace

Tags: javascript, replace, css-variables

Я изучаю запоминая слова в Анкидроид и там каждая карточка по сути веб страница, все под себя настраивется.

Так вот на примере слова estimate есть скрипт для замены гласных на * и получается это так *st*m*t*, и мне нужно добавить еще одно условие
что бы согласные заменить на плюсики, чтоб получился
следующий шифр *++*+*+*. Очень помагает как подсказка к слову.

HELP!

```
<script language="JavaScript">
//Replace vowel
var str = document.getElementById("dropped-vowel").innerHTML;
letters = '';
for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
if (str[i].match(/[aeoui]/i)) {
letters += '<span class="hint">' + '*' + '</span>';
} else {
letters += str[i];
}
}
document.getElementById("dropped-vowel").innerHTML = letters;

</script>
```

Comment: "и получается это так stmt" - нет так не получается, если заменять гласные на `*`, то получается `*st*m*t*`. "согласные заменить на плюсики, чтоб получился следующий шифр ++++" - если согласные заменить на `+`, то получится `*++*+*+*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так Вы хотели что-бы получилось:

```js
var str = document.getElementById("dropped-vowel").innerHTML;
letters = '';
for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
  if (str[i].match(/[aeoui -]/i)) {
    letters += str[i];
  } else {
    letters += '+';
  }
}
document.getElementById("dropped-vowel").innerHTML = letters;
```

```html
<p id="dropped-vowel">show-off</p>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось, еще хотелось добавить условие чтоб дефисы и пробелы в слове не заменялись. К приеру слова вроле таких show-off, half-brother и т.д.

Comment: @ЕрланЕ Откорректировал код.